# Read CSV file uploaded in S3 amazon

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-s3

I have a problem, I upload a file in amazon and I can get the url and the amazon key file but when i try to read the file in my model with
CSV.read(file_path, headers: true)
I get the error No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen, what I can do for read the file?

Comment: did you try to use the SDK (getItem) to read the content of the file uploaded and process the string? Perhaps it's out of scope here, but just a tip.

Answer (score 1):

`CSV.read()` needs the file to be a local on-disk filename, file handle or IO object, but your Amazon key file or URL is not one of those things.

You'll likely need to download the contents to a file (or Tempfile), then read it with something like this:

```
require 'open-uri' # gives us the `open()` method in this namespace

open(amazon_url) do |file|
  CSV.read(file, headers: true) do |csv|
    # do something with csv data here
  end
end
```